# Ruby - Comparing "==" hex value to string

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, hex

I am basically reading in the header of a picture file and doing a quick comparison to see what kind of file it actually is. BMP, GIF, PNG are all easy as their headers contain BM, GIF, and PNG respectively to identify themselves. JPG is throwing me for a bit of a loop tho.

The first 3 bytes of a jpg tend to be 0xff\0xd8\0xff and for the life of me I can't get a true value in a simple comparison no matter how I set it up.

I read in the first 4 bytes:

```
if data[0, 3] == "\xff\xd8\xff"
    puts "This is a JPG"
end
```

I know I am close but I just can't get it to work. Please let me know what I'm missing out on here.

Note: I know there are gems to do this for me but I don't want to use a gem. Simple as that.

Comment: How your data looks like?

Comment: @Anand I use data[0, 3] to get the first 3 bytes of the 4 that I read in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a character encoding issue. Reading the first 4 bytes from a JPEG returns an ASCII encoded string:

```
head = File.read("some.jpg", 4)
# => "\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE1"

head.encodig
# => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Strings on the other hand are UTF-8 encoded:

```
jpg_prefix = "\xff\xd8\xff"
# => "\xFF\xD8\xFF"

jpg_prefix.encoding
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comparing UTF-8 and ASCII strings does not work as expected:

```
head[0,3] == jpg_prefix
# => false
```

You have to explicitly set the encoding with [`String#force_encoding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding):

```
jpg_prefix = "\xff\xd8\xff".force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
# => "\xFF\xD8\xFF"

jpg_prefix.encoding
# => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

head[0,3] == jpg_prefix
# => true
```

Concatenating ASCII characters created with [`Integer#chr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Integer.html#method-i-chr) (as suggested by Mario Visic) also works:

```
jpg_prefix = 0xff.chr + 0xd8.chr + 0xff.chr
# => "\xFF\xD8\xFF"

jpg_prefix.encoding
# => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Or by using [`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack):

```
jpg_prefix = ["FFD8FF"].pack("H*")
# => "\xFF\xD8\xFF"

jpg_prefix.encoding
# => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me when Data is a string - but Data is likely an array of byte values.

Try this:

```
if data[0,3] == [0xff, 0xd8, 0xff]
```

as your condition.

Comment: Im still a bit new to ruby and such. Im using IO to read in 4 bytes from an actual JPG file and I think that it reads in hex values in string form(?) but not completely sure. Anyways, the array was a good idea, but didn't work :/

Comment: Is your string perhaps in a different character set encoding to that which you expect?  Have you printed out the first three bytes of the string and verified the byte values?

Comment: I also found that to be a pain. If I use `puts` to display the data it always seems to show up as ????. I did confirm that it is reading in the correct data tho

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compare the file information with the character codes, something like:

```
if data[0, 3] == 0xff.chr + 0xd8.chr + 0xff.chr
  puts "This is a JPG"
end
```

If you get stuck you can always peek the the fastimage gem's code, the type detection code is here: https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage/blob/master/lib/fastimage.rb#L337-L354

Like others (@Stefan) mentioned, the strings did not match in your original example because the encodings differed.

```
# Check the encodings for our strings:
"\xff\xd8\xff".encoding                   #=> <Encoding:UTF-8>
(0xff.chr + 0xd8.chr + 0xff.chr).encoding #=> <Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

# Compare our two strings with different encodings:
utf8  = "\xff\xd8\xff"
ascii = 0xff.chr + 0xd8.chr + 0xff.chr

utf8 == ascii                              #=> false
utf8.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT") == ascii #=> true
```

Your original code actually would have worked fine if you forced the encoding to be ASCII-8BIT

Comment: Your solution worked! Could you explain to me a bit how it works so I can understand it?

Comment: Stefan's answer does a very good job of explaining it though; you should check his answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Identifying files is a good thing to let someone else do, if you can.  The [ruby-filemagic](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic) gem will do this.

```
gem 'ruby-filemagic'
```

In use, it returns a string:

```
require 'filemagic'

magic = FileMagic.new
p magic.file("/tmp/pic1.jpg")
# => "JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02"
```

The returned string can be matched against regular expressions:

```
case magic.file(path)
when /JPEG/
  # do JPEG stuff
when /GIF/
  # do GIF stuff
else
  # we don't recognize it
end
```

ruby-filemagic uses the [libmagic](http://www.darwinsys.com/file) library, which recognizes a great number of file types.

The documentation is a little sparse (the README doesn't even have a "hello world" example), and it hasn't been updated in a few years, but don't let that deter you from trying it.  It's simple enough to use, and pretty solid--I've got production code using it today, and it still works fine.

If, for some reason, you are unable to use the gem, but are in a *nix environment and have access to the "file" command, you can get the same functionality by shelling out to "file":

```
p `file /tmp/pic1.jpg`
# => "/tmp/pic1.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02\n
```

In Debian, the *file* command is provided by package *file*.  Your OS may differ.